# understanding pointer to array of pointers to integer type

Tags: c, pointers, arguments

In a given exercise in `C` programming language, there is a function that should return an **array of arrays** (`out` in the function `foo` signature) of `"pairs"` of `integer` variables `[ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], .... ]`

The prototype looks like this:

```
void foo(int*** out)
{
   ....
}
```

1. What is the meaning of the argument format?
2. Does the functions receives a pointer to the out array, or does it have to allocate the memory for the the array by itself?

Comment: Its a pointer to pointer to pointer to int.

Comment: probably, the function `foo` needs to generate (on the heap for sure) an array of pointers to int type and return it by derefrence the `out` parameter/function argument

Comment: visibly *foo* has to allocate your array and set the in-out variable *out* with its address, this is why your function is *void* rather than `int**`

Comment: Most likely your source of learning doesn't know how to [Correctly allocate multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). That post also deals with "three star programming" and other such confused anti-patterns.

Comment: @Lundin: *Sometimes* multiple indirection is not the wrong answer.  Not saying that's the case here, but it's not necessarily an anti-pattern.

Comment: @JohnBode In the rare case where you need to return a `type**` through parameters, then yeah there is a valid use-case for `type***`. But most often the need for more than 2 levels of indirection is a sign of bad program design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description, the most *likely* interpretation is that you are passing a pointer to an `int **` object, and `foo` allocates memory for that object, so you'd have

```
void foo( int ***out )
{
  *out = ...; // omitting actual allocation here since it's homework,
              // but I can guarantee it won't be a single statement
}

int main( void )
{
  int **pairs;
  ...
  foo( &pairs ); 
  ...
}
```

Note than an object of `T **` is *not* a 2-dimensional array; it can be used to implement something that can be indexed like a 2D array, but the "rows" don't have to be contiguous or even the same length.  It basically looks something like this:

```
pairs       pairs[i]        pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]
int **      int *           int
+---+       +---+           +---+---+
| +-+-----> | +-+---------> |   |   |
+---+       +---+           +---+---+
            | +-+------+
            +---+      |    +---+---+
            | +-+---+  +--> |   |   |
            +---+   |       +---+---+
             ...    |     
                    |       +---+---+
                    +-----> |   |   |
                            +---+---+
```

IOW, you have an object `pairs` that points to a sequence of `int *`, each of which (`pairs[i]`) points to a sequence of `int`.  Because of how the `[]` subscript operator works, you can index into this structure using 2D array notation (`pairs[i][j]`), but otherwise it doesn't look or act like a 2D array.

So I'm assuming the job of `foo` is to allocate the memory for a structure like that, where each `pairs[i]` points to a sequence of 2 `int`.  Since it needs to write a new value to `pairs`, we need to pass a *pointer* to `pairs`.  Since `pairs` has type `int **`, that means the expression `&pairs` has type `int ***`.

I can tell you this will be a multi-step process - you will need to make multiple calls to `malloc` or `calloc`.  The diagram above should give you some hints on how to do that.

Comment: Very clear and useful. The diagram is very good and helps more than many words. Thanks!